# Discord OAuth .net core 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, discord

I am trying to authorize my web app with this library:
https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.OAuth2

I have everything setup as far as I know, but I receive the following error when I try to call the login page:

```
The SignInScheme for a remote authentication handler cannot be set to itself. If it was not explicitly set, the AuthenticationOptions.DefaultSignInScheme or DefaultScheme is used.
```

Here's how I have my startup.cs class:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddDiscord(x =>
        {
            x.AppId = Configuration["Discord:AppId"];
            x.AppSecret = Configuration["Discord:AppSecret"];
            x.Scope.Add("guilds");
        })
}
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseStaticFiles();
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc(routes =>
    {
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "default",
            template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
    });
}
```

EDIT:

I was able to figure out how to get the response to work by adding the following to ConfigureServices:

```
            services.AddAuthentication(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddCookie(o => o.LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"))
            .AddDiscord(x =>
            {
                x.AppId = Configuration["Discord:AppId"];
                x.AppSecret = Configuration["Discord:AppSecret"];
                x.Scope.Add("guilds");
            });
```

But now I'm getting an UNKNOWN_ERROR from Discord. The url string looks like this:

```
https://discordapp.com/oauth2/authorize?client_id=472181242998292481&scope=identify%20guilds&response_type=code&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A56214%2Fsignin-discord&state=CfDJ8CURg60yxjRJi8TTHjISMApdIG0cpQhUrb2ylVaYV9uLT-D_Lp0MKDwpuMEW-lUJl18LQcSCn3-fNNaCQXKnxIJPTd4o1n5GnPcjvNuGGJJ4NrhcErxVcZzY0sGi8BiRNSBV-_t2Gc_Su6mV5hNLo6gTLzniljt42VQaRkkHZ6qF7nie1C47Wrc-ZK0F6k13570bd1GnkeXzsnsQy0TFx3k6kWI1Y7Ms_uxvPivG-H09ZGZhPcM3GjxffKdISDfvzQ
```

Any ideas on this new error?

Comment: That looks like a case of the redirect URI not matching between the discord application definition and what the local application is generating. maybe the app definition doesn't have the port specified?